# Weight and distension length of the "Gates Carbon Drive Eco Tension Tester"

Tags: tools, belt-drive, tension, gates

I own a bike with a gates CDX belt drive. I noticed that my belt tension was way too low and tightened it, but I have no belt tension tester. I find that measuring the frequency of the belt "swinging" is way too imprecise - I get a different result every time I try it.

I could buy a "Gates Carbon Drive Eco Tension Tester" for ~40 €, which is basically a weight and a ruler. I don't want to spend 40 € for a lump of metal and a ruler. ;-)

If I knew the weight of the weight, and the distension lengths (i.e., how far the belt should be pushed down by the weight) of the red, yellow and green areas, I could probably improvise the same thing without buying anything.

Does anybody have this tension testing tool and could measure the weight of the weight and the length of the areas? That would be great!